# Поиск в БД через AJAX, Логика очередности выполнения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть поле поиска по базе.

```
<input id="search">
```

Есть Ajax скрипт с запросом который после выполнения перерисовывает либо добавляет данные в таблицу в браузере. Данных много, скрипт тоже тяжеленький.
Скрипт привязан на событие onChange / onInput поля.

Суть такова. Если в AJAX запросе отключить асинхронность, то все работает как надо. Браузер стопорится, ждет окончание запроса, выводит инфу, оживает и ждет дальнейших действий. (изменение строки поиска).

Но если асинхронность включить, то время поиска по разному кол-ву букв отличается. И В итоге при наборе 3-4х букв скрипт мне видает информацию по 1 или 2-й букве.

Я уже придумал что то типа семафоров, которые не дают запускаться новому запросу, пока старый не обработался, но натолкнулся на такую проблему:

Если во время выполнения запроса пытаемся нажать еще пару букв, то они выполняться не будут, ибо отменяется запуск запроса, пока старый не отработается.

Конечно можно сделать в обработчике полученных данных вызов самого себя при признаке что строка поиска изменилась, но возможно до меня уже все решили.

Comment: Количество данных ограничивается на сервере или приходят все по набранной букве?

Comment: По набранной букве. (Upper(value) contains Upper(searchString))

Comment: если при первом запросе приходят все данные, то, возможно их надо закэшировать и затем уже искать в них, а не обращаться на сервер

Comment: Не получится. Запрос выводит не все поля поиска.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё что вам нужно сделать, это не забывать про созданный для поиска объект запроса, и для нового поиска, если запрос уже существует вызывать его [прерывание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) (для jquery тоже можно `var rq = $.ajax(...); rq.abort();`).

Comment: Ай спасибо Добрый человек. Помогло

Comment: Не знал про такую фишку. Вопрос - сервер ведь все равно будет выполнять свой скрипт до конца?

Comment: Да, судя по времени срабатывания сервак запрос исполняет. Но в моем случае это не критично, Главное что интерфейс стал отзывчивый.

Comment: @Skywave да. Чтобы сократить количество запросов к серверу можно использовать технику, о которой вы написали (с таймауотом).

Answer (score -1):

1 вариант - запрещать ввод в поле пока не завершится запрос. Тут либо добавить readonly, либо может быть поверх невидимый блок положить, и не забыть focus снять с поля.

2 вариант - кроме запрета выполнения запросов пока предыдущий не закончился добавить ожидание, например делать запрос когда человек 1 секунду ничего не вводил.

```
var timeout;
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    request();
  });
});
```

3 вариант - хранить признак того, что надо сделать еще один запрос на случай, если человек что-то вводил пока выполнялся текущий запрос

```
var lateRequest = false,
    requestProcess = false;
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
  if (requestProcess) {
    lateRequest = true;
  } else {
    request();
  }
});

function request() {
  requestProcess = true;
  $.ajax({
    complete: function(){
      // обработка ответа...
      if (lateRequest) {
        lateRequest = false;
        request();
      } else {
        requestProcess = false;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Только тут надо будет еще проверить ситуации, когда запросы могут слаться бесконечно один за одним))

Ну и можно совместить все три варианта

P.S. 4 вариант - добавить кнопку submit =)